# file_get_contents for a specific ( a tag ) from external website URL - PHP

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I read every single stackoverflow questions and I try each one but nothing works for me.

I have this HTML in the external webpage:

```
<a href="/gallery/image1.png" id="viewbt">
<div class="view"></div>
</a>
```

I want to get this whole code using any kind of PHP codes.

Comment: Congratulations for having read 39,012,055 questions! [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) can accept an external URL to load a web page. 

If you want to parse out a link from a chunk of HTML code, you may want to read on [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match).

Comment: @rationalboss Regular expressions probably shouldn't be used, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/.

Comment: haha @rationalboss I will.

Comment: Consider using DOMDocument to parse the fetched content.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, while going to a specific HTML tag is a browser feature. There is still a way. You will need to fetch that page and search for the exact tag with regex or with DOM manipulation.

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://your_php_subpage.com');
// to find the specific tag ( for example the image link )
if(preg_match('#<a href="(.*?)" id="viewbt">.*?</a>#', $str, $m)){
     var_dump($m);
} else {
    echo 'Regex syntax has to be improved to your search criteria'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Extra info for regex:
http://php.net/preg_match

I suggest regarding a regex tutorial as well, besides the PHP function. You can do a lot more.

Comment: Regex is not a html parser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/ use DOMDocument.

Comment: thanks for reply but all what I get is: Regex syntax has to be improved to your search criteria

Comment: This means that you hit the exception of regex, are there any special characters that you want to fetch ?